# Ubuntu icon missing from repo links

Tags: discussion, image

I've just noticed on some questions [like this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21768/software-to-create-a-video-slideshow) there is an "image not found" link for imgur. I think it used to be an icon for the Ubuntu package manager.

At first I thought these were added automatically on any link to the package manager, but it looks like the user Sid has edited the questions to add links and images in manually.

I don't know how many other questions he or others have edited. Is there a way to mass-correct/remove these missing images?

Answer (score 2):

The Bitly links just need updating. We should be able to do this without editing posts (so please leave them broken for the moment).

I've pinged Marco (who controls these image URLs).

Comment: Can we use something more … canonical than opaque bitly links?

Comment: Like what? I'm not uninterested in finding something better but this was set up in a way that *we* could do (and edit) without external interaction/wait but was also easy to use.

Comment: (Ideally we'd have a `[package:...]` markdown extension but I can't imagine SE would sink that sort of development time just to make linking to packages easier)

Comment: Any updates from Marco? Does he have a paid Bitly account to change these URLs?